# Read results of callSingle similar to callonce

Tags: karate

Is it possible to read results of callSingle into the current scope, similar to callonce?

With callonce, we can simply read the result of the feature and the results are added as a part of the current scope.

ie...`* callonce read('callonceVScallsingleInfo.feature')`

I tried a few different ways (can provide examples if it won't get overcomplicated) but was unable to read the results of the callSingle call.  The only way, I have found, to access the values from the callSingle call was to assign the result to a variable.

ie...`* def constants = karate.callSingle('callonceVScallsingleInfo.feature')`

Since our constants have quite a few variables (all returned as json object), and the file is shared across multiple features, it would be very cumbersome to prefix each value with constants.xxx rather than simply calling the variable xxx itself.

Currently we use the callonce method in the background of our feature files, but as we add more feature files, we would like to limit the calling of this file to run just once across all calling feature files.  We could put the values in the config, but that would require us to limit which feature files get what value for each variable, as we use different values for different sets of feature files.

Comment: possibly related to https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/issues/2333

Answer (score 0):

Once you have any JSON object you can dump all the keys within it as variables in one-shot using [`karate.set(json)`](https://github.com/karatelabs/karate#karate-set). In fact this is what `call / callonce` does behind the scenes.

So this should work:

```
* karate.set(constants)
```